Data sets for articles on Cognitive Sciences
Most of the question and answers in this site refer to an article of research to support hypothesis with facts. Since all these hypothesis must have been based on some data, can such raw data can be accessed. Shortly, can data sets to articles on cognitive sciences is freely available?

From my experience, getting access to datasets from published papers is not as easy as it should be.
A few options:

You can contact authors of publications and see whether they will provide you with a copy of the dataset. Some journals and societies require that the authors make the data available at least for verification purposes, unless compelling reasons exist for not making the data available. However, I've read many reports, and have my own experiences, of not getting access as a result of data requests.
I asked a question about general data repositories in the cognitive science 
A few authors provide data on their website or in institutional repositories.

In summary, it should be easier than it is.
